# ios 10 auto resizing interface elements

Tags: ios, autolayout

Please help me with this auto layout issue of IOS. I have a view with two buttons in it. I am using the auto resizing property to align my elements. Their position is staying same when I change the screen, but, the size of the elements is not changing. You can see in the image, I have screens for iphone 4s and 6s plus. The frame size is changing according to the screen size but not the content inside of it. How can I make the button look good on all the screens. I have tried using the auto layout constraints to position my elements, but they are pretty much confusing to my knowledge on IOS.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you trying AutoResize OR AutoLayout both of them are different approach.

Comment: Add you image of autoresize constraints you have added on these two buttons.

Comment: Hey sumit, thanks for the response. I am just using the autoresizing property. And I added the image you were asking for.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make the button look good on all the screens

This depends on what you mean by "look good". From the way you ask your question, it *seems* to refer to the *font* size of the text. If you want the font size of the button text to be different on different screen sizes, you will have to write *code* that takes care of that; it cannot be configured in some automatic way in the storyboard.

Comment: So, is there any way I could relate the font size with the frame size of the button??

Comment: Sure, but you'd have to do it _in code_. If you change the font size and you are using auto layout correct, the button will simply grow or shrink to accommodate its text at the current size. But the font size change must be made in code.